# jQuery iterate through .each() and give iteration id based on first .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Had no idea how to properly name the problem, so apologise for the title if its misleading.

I have a list of `tables` (around 30~) that i'm loading with `ajax` from other file depending on which `li data-id` on the `sidebar menu` user is clicking. And each of the `table` has it's own `id` and each `input` in `td` its own `id` based on `table id` and the numbers of inputs in `table`.

I.e: `table#id_1` has an `input#id_1--input2` (`input2` cus it's the 3rd `input` in this specific `table`).

I could manually do the writing, but i'm sorting my list alphabetically, so if I will want to add a new `table` which will go in the middle of the `list` I will have to rewrite like half of the `table's` and `input's` `id's` which is a *big* nay.

So i'm trying to get a function that can add `id attribute` to `table` and based on `table id` it can set `input id` + add an index of it at the end of `input` (like in an example above and in the `effect i want` at the end of the snippet).

```js
var div = $('table');

div.each(function(index){
  var inputid = index - 2;
  
  $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+index);
  
  $('input').each(function(inputIndex){
    $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+inputid+'-input'+inputIndex);
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

span{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>The effect i'm receiving:</span>
<div>
Table 1 //#id_0
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_0-input0
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_0-input1
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_0-input2
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
Table 2 //#id_1
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_0-input3
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_0-input4
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
Table 3 //#id_2
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> ...
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label>
      <input type="number"> ...
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label>
      <input type="number"> //input_0-input7
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<span>The effect I want:</span> 
<div>
Table 1 //#id_0
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_0-input0
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_0-input1
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_0-input2
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
Table 2 //#id_1
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_1-input0
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_1-input1
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
Table 3 //#id_2
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> //id_2-input0
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label>
      <input type="number"> //id_2-input1
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label>
      <input type="number"> //id_2-input2
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? why do you need those specific `ID`s?

Comment: Well can be `class`es aswell to be honest. It's just an advanced physics calculator (like you can calculate black hole temperature) i'm doing for practice and each table has it's own formula and own calculations. Thats why i have a lot of inputs, since i need to get values from each of it and then to the specific formula make calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your javascript code to this:

```
var div = $('table');

div.each(function(index){
  var inputid = index;

  $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+index);

  $(this).find('input').each(function(inputIndex){
     $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+inputid+'-input'+inputIndex);
  });
});
```

Notice the fourthe last line is

`$(this).find('input').each(...)`

You we're reiterating all the `input`s again, instead we're now only iterating the `input`s in the `div` we were iterating over.

As user S McCrohan mentioned in the comments:
`var inputid = index - 2;`
Is unnecessary and should be:
`var inputid = index;`

**edit**: 
https://jsfiddle.net/xxL5tuvw/

Comment: Beat me to it. However, you should also correct `index - 2` to just `index` if you want the precise shape in the desired example. (Or remove that line entirely and correct the reference below)

Comment: Agreed, should I edit my answer or would your comment be sufficient?

Comment: @TimvanOsch I will correct that on fly, thank you for your answer, time and the explanation of it! Appreciate that (:

Comment: I'd edit it; it makes the answer more clear for future readers.

Comment: @nehel If this answered your question, then consider marking it as **answer**

Answer (score 1):

```js
var div = $('div');

div.each(function(index){   
  $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+index);
  
  $('input', this).each(function(inputIndex){
     var id = 'id_'+index+'-input'+inputIndex;
     $(this).attr('id', id).after('<span>' + id+ '</span>');
     // above .after() to show the id, u can remove it 
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

span{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>The effect i'm receiving:</span>
<div>
Table 1 //#id_0
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number">
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> 
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> 
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
Table 2 //#id_1
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> 
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number"> 
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
Table 3 //#id_2
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label> 
      <input type="number">
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label>
      <input type="number">
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label for="">item</label>
      <input type="number">
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```